# Temporal interpolation in NumPy/matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, paraview

When creating animations in ParaView there is a function to [temporally interpolate input files](http://paraview.org/OnlineHelpCurrent/TemporalInterpolator.html). When generating an animation via multiple contour plots in NumPy/matplotlib is there a similar function which can help make the animation smoother or do I have to temporal interpolate the data manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VTK's `TemporalInterpolator` is for interpolating data on unstructured spacial meshes between time steps.  You have your data in two-dimensional NumPy arrays, and the task of interpolating it is far easier.  For this reason, there is no dedicated function for this, and you'll have to do it manually.

Let's assume `a0` is your two-dimensional data array at the time `t0`, and `a1` is the data at `t1`.  For some time `t0 <= t <= t1`, the linearly interpolated data `a_t` is

```
delta_t = t1 - t0
a_t = (t1 - t) / delta_t * a_0 + (t - t0) / delta_t * a_1
```

There are more advanced interpolation schemes than this simple linear interpolation, but VTK's `TemporalInterpolator` also uses this simple scheme.